# Laravel Vite assets not loading in production

Tags: laravel, vite, assets, production

I have a Laravel app that I deployed to Forge. When I try accessing it however, the Vite build assets are not loaded.

Now, Firefox says it's a CORS issue, Chrome says its an SSL issue. While I don't yet have SSL on the site (due to Forge bugging out), I don't think either of these are actually true.

Even with a CORS allowed extension, and Chrome running with --ignore-certificate-errors, the same errors persist. From my experience with Vite so far, it's not uncommon for assets not being loaded to be interpreted as an entirely unconnected error. And besides which, if it were true, it would be affecting other assets as well, not just Vite's JS and CSS.

I am able to run npm run build on the server, seeing as how Vite doesn't have a separate production script, but it doesn't really change anything.

Needless to say this works in development but I have not been able to figure out what could be causing this in production.

Error screenshot https://i.imgur.com/0lsXOo4.png

My vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';
// import cors from "cors";
import fs from 'fs';


export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
        template: {
            compilerOptions: {
                isCustomElement: (tag) => ['Tags'].includes(tag),
            }
        },
    }),
    basicSsl(),
],
server: {
    // port: 3000,
    // https: true,
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
        // port: 3001,
        protocol: 'wss',
        origin: false,
    },
        // key: fs.readFileSync(`C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key`),
        // cert: fs.readFileSync(`C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt`),
},
resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    server: {
        https: true,
        origin: 'localhost'

    },
    cors: true,

},
```

});

Comment: Go to the network panel. Find the failing requests. Open in a new tab. What happens?

Comment: On Firefox, secure connection failed (even with browser.ssl_override_behavior set to true). On Chrome, this site cannot be reached.

Comment: There should be more detail than that somewhere on the error pages. Give us the URL if you can't find it.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose http://68.183.222.1/ the only other noteworthy thing to me though is Module source URI is not allowed in this document. Only shows up in Firefox.

Comment: You're trying to load your assets over HTTPS without a valid SSL certificate. Use a real domain and valid SSL, or serve everything over HTTP.

Comment: Serving everything over http is what I've been trying to do; The domain name is default which, as I understand it, is only supposed to function with http anyway. Does that mean I need to specify in the Vite config that assets should be served with http?

Comment: Should `https: true,`  be set like this if you don't have ssl?

Comment: I tried changing it but it made no difference. I switched it back since I didn't want to mess with what worked in development too much. Turns out all I had to do was add ASSET_URL= with a htttp address in my .env.